# Filtering multiple specific values from line of Log in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, logging, awk, sed

I have Logs with these type of lines:

```
"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000" client=10.0.0.148 method=GET request="GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1" [...] request_time=0.011 [...] upstream_header_time=0.010
```

I have managed to extract singular values out of the log (e.g. only the request time) like this:

```
cat <logfile> | sed -n -e 's/^.*request_time=//p' | sed -n -e 's/ .*$//p'
```

I would like to filter the values so that i receive the following:

```
"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000" "GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1" 0.011
```

This being:

```
<time> <request> <request-time>
```

How would such a thing be accomplished?

Comment: Try `sed 's/^\("[^"]*"\).*request=\("[^"]*"\).*=\([0-9.]*\)$/\1 \2 \3/'`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/jlVNdV).

Answer (score 0):

with `grep`

```
$ grep -oP '^"[^"]+"|request(|_time)=\K("[^"]+"|\S+)' file | paste -s

"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000"    "GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1"  0.011
```

based on the output, you're getting **request**, not **method**.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this using GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^[:space:]=]+=)?(\"[^\"]+\"|[^[:space:]]+)"
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print i, "<" $i ">"
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 <"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000">
2 <client=10.0.0.148>
3 <method=GET>
4 <request="GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1">
5 <[...]>
6 <request_time=0.011>
7 <[...]>
8 <upstream_header_time=0.011>
```

Given the above method of parsing your input you can easily identify which fields you want to output and even reference them simply by name or position, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^[:space:]=]+=)?(\"[^\"]+\"|[^[:space:]]+)"
}
{
    f["time"] = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = val = $i
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^=]+=/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }

    print f["time"], f["request"], f["request_time"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000" "GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1" 0.011
```

Think about how easy that'd be to modify in future when you want to additionally print the client IP address and method in a CSV in a specific order of fields with all fields double quoted or do just about anything else, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^[:space:]=]+=)?(\"[^\"]+\"|[^[:space:]]+)"
    OFS=","
}
{
    f["time"] = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = val = $i
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^=]+=/,"",val)
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
        f[tag] = "\"" val "\""
    }

    print f["time"], f["request"], f["request_time"], f["client"], f["method"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000","GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1","0.011","10.0.0.148","GET"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl one-liner

```
perl -ne ' /(^.+?").+?request=(.+?").+?request_time=(\S+)/ and print "$1 $2 $3" '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat  req.logs
"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000" client=10.0.0.148 method=GET request="GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1" [...] request_time=0.011 [...] upstream_header_time=0.010


$ perl -ne ' /(^.+?").+?request=(.+?").+?request_time=(\S+)/ and print "$1 $2 $3" ' req.logs
"09/Feb/2019:11:25:51 +0000" "GET /flask2 HTTP/1.1" 0.011
$
```